# Magento 2 how to show another text if price is > 2000?

Tags: magento2, product, price, addtocart

**I want to show custom text instead of the price if the product price is > 20000.**

**if price > 20000 then I want to show "contact for price" instead of price.**

**Also, I need to hide the add to cart button as well.**

How can I achieve this functionality?

I am using Magento 2.3.3

if anyone has any idea about it please share!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this as a base

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CallForPrice

But instead of looking at call for price attribute check price is over 20000

Or alternatively set any over 20000 as call for price

Either on cron / console or via admin grid bulk actions

Answer (score 0):

You can override the price phtml using your custom theme file and get product price over there and compare your price using if condition if price is greater then your given price show your custom text otherwise default functionality.